# How to compile php5-cgi out of PHP source code?

Tags: php, fastcgi, lamp

I've only compiled php itself from source,

how is php-cgi generated?

Answer (score 1):

Add `--enable-fastcgi` and remove `--disable-cgi` from the parameters of the `configure` script as noted in the [List of core configure options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php).

Comment: What's the name of the generated fastcgi executable?

Comment: The binary is named `php-cgi`.

Comment: But I don't see that executable after `make install`

Comment: Then check the output of `configure` and `make`…